# How to Host a Visual Studio Web Application in Docker?

Tags: .net, postgresql, docker

I am running docker 17.09.1-ce version on my Windows machine. I configured a PostgreSQL database on a Linux container of same machine that gets access through an IP address. Now I want to host my web application (Visual Studio 2015) on Docker IIS? How do I host my VS Web App in Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cteate Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/iis:10.0.14393.206  
SHELL ["powershell"]

RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET ; \  
    Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45

COPY <your app folder> MyApp  
# remove the old site if you want. 
RUN Remove-WebSite -Name 'Default Web Site'  
RUN New-Website -Name 'MyApp' -Port 80 \  
    -PhysicalPath 'c:\MyApp' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'
EXPOSE 80

# for docker logs 
CMD Write-Host IIS Started... ; \  
while ($true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 }
```

build container

```
docker build -t MyApp .
```

Use -p 80:80 to expose port 80 from IIS.

```
docker run --name myapp -d -p 80:80 MyApp
```

Comment: Hi, thank for your help but when i am trying to build the file by using command "docker build -t path ." its not working. But by giving "docker build path" the file is building and throwing an issue.

Comment: docker build -t path . invalid argument "d:\\CRM\\Dockerfile" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format

Comment: I will wait you in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164553/how-to-host-a-visual-studio-web-application-in-docker) please, go to chat for discussing